# Set an image height = 70% inside an htmlString ( webView ) Xcode

Tags: html, uiwebview, uiscrollview, xcode4.3

I have a uiwebview loaded inside a UIScrollView..i Load inside the webView an HTMLString using this code :

```
    NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                             <html>\
                             <table width='960'>\<tr>\<td>\
                             <body>\
                             <p style = 'font-size:25px;'> %@ <\p>\
                             </td></tr><tr><td><br><br></td></tr><tr><td align ='center'><br><img src='%@' height='600px'\><br></td></tr></body>\
                             </table>\
                             </html>",authorNAme , cachePath];

    WebV.opaque = NO;
    WebV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    [self.WebV setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.WebV loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Instead of Height = '600px' i need height = 70% of the original image height...if i write height = '70%' , Xcode will take it as 70 px or so and just won't work...how can i fix this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 70%% instead of 70%

Answer (score 1):

Write like:

```
height = 70%%
```

When you write like:

```
height = 70%
```

Xcode will expect an escape sequence after that.

> In format strings, a ‘%’ character announces a placeholder for a
>   value, with the characters that follow determining the kind of value
>   expected and how to format it.